# Finding a particular string in a xml file using grep if that string is a substring of another string?

Tags: xml, string, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
I = `grep -R --include="*.xml" "Non Frontal Face" /home/ashutosh/Desktop/imgdone | grep "Frontal Face" > temp.txt`
cut -d':' -f1 temp.txt > out.txt
cat out.txt
```

What I want is that all the xmls having "Frontal Face" should only be displayed, but instead of that in the result I get all the files and wherever "Non Frontal Face" string is present, I get "**Frontal Face**" highlighted in bold.

Please help me out !! ?

Comment: The expression is wrong, you say `var=$(command)`. Spaces around `=` are incorrect and make Bash to interpret `var = $(command)` as "execute the command `var` with the parameters `=` and `$(command)`.

Comment: Show us a sample of your input XML and the desired output.

Comment: Non Frontal Face_ Happy is my attribute of any given xml. I want that any xml having "Frontal Face" should be detected. In that case, what shall I do ?

Comment: Do exactly what Tom told you. Show a small sample of your XML document, and show the output you expect. `grep` might be the wrong tool for this.

Comment: `grep` is the wrong tool for XML almost categorically. It doesn't understand entity encodings (an XML file can declare that `&f;` is short for `Face` in its header, and `grep` won't understand that `Non Frontal &f;` means `Non Frontal Face` -- likewise for built-in encodings like `&amp;` for ampersands. It doesn't understand comments, it doesn't understand CDATA sections, you can't do structure- or context-aware matching... simply the Wrong Tool For The Job, when XML-aware tools that do all these things right are available.

Comment: In this case, I'm assuming that you have a specific element or attribute you're looking to have be exactly `Frontal Face`, with no prefix such as `Non`. That's trivial if you can do structurally-aware search.

Comment: Charles, could you please tell me how to do structurally-aware search if I want that attribute only

Comment: I already answered that. Find an XPath tool to your liking. `xmlstarlet` seems to be popular, but what's available and supported also depends on your platform.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove the "Non Frontal Face" from the "Frontal Face" matches?

```
grep -R --include="*.xml" "Frontal Face" /home/ashutosh/Desktop/imgdone |
grep -v "Non Frontal Face"
```

If you want just the file nmes, pipe that to `cut -d : -f 1`. There is no need for a temporary file, and the odd command substitution with a syntax error was completely superfluous.

(If you fixed the syntax error with the whitespace around the equals sign, `I` would end up containing an empty string, because you were redirecting all the output to a file anyway. You were not using `I` for anything anyhow, so it was doubly or triply superfluous.)

Comment: Could you please also tell how to search xmls having multiple attributes. In addition to this, suppose I have to search for some more keywords, how can I integrate it in the same  piece of code !! ?

Comment: In the general case, you want something like XPath to properly manipulate XML. Using line-oriented tools for structured formats is usually a bad idea, although it can be done in limited circumstances.

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate as to how should I proceed ?...In the same bash script, how should I search for attributes like "Happy" "Cartoon" etc. ??

Comment: Your original question wasn't clear at all, and your follow-up questions here aren't very clear, either. Soulds like you should post a separate new question, hopefully this time with a clear statement of what you want to achieve, and where you are stuck.

Comment: Okay, I will do that also, please comment on that also :P , thanks btw

Comment: If you are simply asking, "how do I search for multiple strings instead of one string," regular expressions kind of do that. Try `grep -E 'Happy|Cartoon' files` where `-E` enables a set of convenient syntax extensions to the regex formalism (without `-E` you'll need `\|` instead of just `|`).

Comment: There is nothing here which focuses the search on just XML attributes, though. If that is important, use a proper XML tool instead of `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help

```
grep -Rl "Frontal Face" *.xml |grep -v "Non Frontal Face" > out.txt
```

-l tell grep to print only the name of the file.

Comment: It's still doing the same thing, the term "Frontal Face" is getting highlighted even if the term is "Non Frontal Face" as Frontal Face is a substring of Non....Face

Comment: Is that to say that the highlighting is part of your question (ie. that it's not limited strictly to selection of the correct lines, but also highlighting the correct subsets)? I would suggest being more explicit about that.

Comment: Guys, when I query for "Frontal Face"-(i) (as I am interested in obtaining those xmls where this word is coming, only this string), but I get the xmls where "Non Frontal Face"-(ii) is written as (i) is a substring of (ii). I want that only those xmls should be given as output where only (i) comes and not (ii).             What tool should I use?

Comment: Sorry, It was unclear in question. Can be this ways: grep -Rl "Frontal Face" *.xml |grep -v "Non Frontal" >  out.txt