# Finding multiple attributes present in an xml with certain conditions using shell scripting

Tags: xml, bash, shell

```
grep -R --include="*.xml" "Frontal Face" /home/ashutosh/Desktop/imgdone | grep -v "Non Frontal Face"
```

This command gives me all xmls where "Frontal Face" is present. If I want to search more attributes through this shell script like "Happy", "Young" (occuring in the xml), what changes shall I do in this?

In summary, how to search for multiple attributes?

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out in the answers and comments to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945768/finding-a-particular-string-in-a-xml-file-using-grep-if-that-string-is-a-substri), there is nothing here which supports specifically searching for XML attributes. `grep` is not a good tool for searching structured formats, as already pointed out [numerous times](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).

If your question is simply "how do I find X, Y, or Z anywhere in a file", that's trivial; `grep -E 'X|Y|Z' files`. But this does nothing to exclude matches which are not in XML attributes, or to find matches which are somehow obscured by the features of XML (such as `X` also being validly representable as `&#88;` or a number of variants of this). Again, this was already pointed out to you previously.

While an XPath expression could be written to say "find any element in the parsed element tree with an attribute whose value is 'baz' or 'quux'", that's not really a sane requirement. Usually, you'd want something like "find any `foo` element in the tree whose `bar` attribute is 'baz' or 'quux', i.e. matches the regular expression `^(baz|quux)$`" which is

```
//foo/@bar[matches(.,'^(baz|quux)$')]
```

The `matches()` predicate is an XPath 2.0 feature.

You'd use it something like

```
find /home/ashutosh/Desktop/imgdone -type f -name '*.xml' -exec \
    xmllint --xpath '//foo/@bar[matches(., "^(baz|quux)$")]' {} \;
```

If your shell is new enough, you can drop the `find` command and just use a recursive wildcard like `/home/ashutosh/Desktop/imgdone/**/*.xml` as the file name argument to `xmllint`.

If you don't have `xmllint`, look for `xmlstarlet` or really any other XPath tool; there is no single ubiquitous standard utility for this (yet).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search specific elements like attributes or values within your xml structure, `xsltproc` or `xmllint` are the way to go, as tripleee has pointed out.

If you just need some "give lines with X or Y" in the same sentence, you can do something like this:

```
grep -E 'X|Y' file
```